# Excel - What is the formula for this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I don't know what formula to put in here.

[image]

I want to sum all the values in amount earned column with a range. For example, the cell where formula entered sums all values in a range of rows like 3-10 only.

Comment: Not clear what you mean, I'm afraid. Please clarify by adding some expected results to your table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but it seems like below might do what you want:

```
=SUM(D3:D10)
```

If this doesn't help, please edit your question to provide additional information

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you wish to sum either the **Amount** (column B) or the **Amount Earned** (Column D) on the rows where the **Term** (column A) is at least **3** but no greater than **10**.

You need a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) for this.

```
=sumifs(B:B, A:A, ">="&3, A:A, "<="&10)
=sumifs(D:D, A:A, ">="&3, A:A, "<="&10)
```

If you computer uses the `;` instead of a `,` for a list separator then those formulas would be,

```
=sumifs(B:B; A:A; ">="&3; A:A; "<="&10)
=sumifs(D:D; A:A; ">="&3; A:A; "<="&10)
```